# How would you get the values of x such that "(x-1) & x" and "(x-1) % 131071" are both zero?

Tags: binary

Recently asked in an interview was how to list all `x` such that

```
((((x - 1) & x) == 0) && ((x - 1) % 131071 == 0))
```

where `x` is a 64-bit unsigned integer.

I was told that 4 integers in total, how to get all the 4 values of `x`?

What approach would be best to take?

Comment: *"List all x that ..."* sounds more like an instruction than a question. Did you have a go at it yet?

Comment: It's a very simple task, what have you tried? Also, StackOverflow is *not* a community where you can ask others to do your homework.

Comment: @Flexo: why "list all x that..." is not a question?

Comment: Hopefully the edits will make it more acceptable as an SO question. It remains to be seen whether it reopens or gets deleted.

Comment: @LaiJiangshan: For starters, there isn't a question mark.

Comment: @paxdiablo nicer title, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`((x - 1) & x) == 0)` means that `x` is either zero, or a power of two (see [this bit twiddling hack](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2)). It works because powers of two are represented as a single 1-bit followed by an arbitrary number of 0-bits (let's say `N` of them).

And, when you subtract one, you always get a number with exactly `N` 1-bits, so anding them together:

```
100000...000
 11111...111
------------
000000...000
```

always gives you zero. Zero is of course a special case since anding anything with zero gives you zero:

```
0000000...000
1111111...111
-------------
0000000...000
```

Since this is a programming Q&A site, see this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    unsigned long long x = 0;
    unsigned long long oldx = x;

    while (x >= oldx) {
        if ((((x - 1ULL) & x) == 0) && (((x - 1ULL) % 131071ULL) == 0))
            printf ("%llu\n", x);
        oldx = x;
        x = (x == 0ULL) ? 1ULL : x * 2ULL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which generates the following *four* values (not three as you suggest):

```
1
131072
17179869184
2251799813685248
```

Comment: Sorry, I was told that 3 integers in total.

Comment: @LaiJiangshan, not sure why you think the approach is wrong. The "trick" to reducing the search space to zero and powers of two is a powerful one and the program to search that space takes about 0.001 seconds on my moderately powered machine.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is 4 integers. Wrong approach is not because the binary "trick". it should have some simple ways, this question should be answered without any help of computers.

Comment: Well, if it's without the benefit of computers, it's hardly a programming question, is it? In any case, you could simply check all 64 values by hand well, with a calculator would be better), it's not _that_ onerous.